# Solve PDE with Laplace or ODE with particulate solution (simplify expression)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

### Question

Find the solution for $u_t = iu_{xx}$, for $ x \in \mathbb R$ and for $t \gt 0$, with the initial condition $u(x,0) = exp(-x^2)$.

### Solution

For the assignment I get to use any transformation method (Laplace, Fourier and possibly separation of variables). I've seen other people solving similar problems with separation but I want to try to solve it with all methods and I am currently stuck trying to find a particular solution for the ODE after using Laplace transformation. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

$$\mathcal L \{u(x,t) \} = U(x,s) = \int_0^\infty u(x,t)e^{-st}dt,$$
$$\mathcal L\{u_t(x,t)\} = sU(x,s) - u(x,0),$$
$$\mathcal L \{u_{xx}(x,t) \} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}U(x,s) = U''(x,s).$$
Inserting into the original equation yields

$$ sU(x,s) - u(x,0) - iU''(x,s) = 0,$$
$$ sU(x,s) - iU''(x,s) = exp(-x^2).$$

### Homogenous solution

For the homogenous solution I get
$$U_h(x,s) = k_1e^{\sqrt{(s/i)}x}+k_2e^{-\sqrt{(s/i)}x}$$

### Particular solution

Using variation of parameters I get that the Wronskian should be $W = -2\sqrt{\frac{s}{i}}$ and

$$ c_1(s) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\sqrt{(s/i)}x-x^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{s}{i}}} ds = \frac{ie^{-x^2}}{x}e^{-x\sqrt{-is}}, $$
$$c_2(s) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{{e^{\sqrt{(s/i)}x-x^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{s}{i}}} ds = \frac{ie^{-x^2}}{x}e^{x\sqrt{-is}}.$$
According to WolframAlpha the particular solution can be written as
$U_p(x,s) = \frac{2ie^{-x^2}}{x}$,
but I don't know how.
Inserting into $U(x,s)$ yields
$$U(x,s) = k_1e^{\sqrt{(s/i)}x}+k_2e^{-\sqrt{(s/i)}x}+\frac{2ie^{-x^2}}{x}.$$
Inserting the solution into $sU-iU''= e^{-x^2}$ I get
$$s\frac{2i}{x}+8x+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{4}{x^3}=1$$
so it doesn't add up. Is there some way to simplify the problem or the expressions?

Comment: Presumably you applied the Laplace transform to $t\mapsto u_t(x,t)$ and to $t\mapsto u_{xx}(x,t)$ keeping $x$ fixed ? If so I do not see how you get this ODE for $U(s)$. Please elaborate. You may also want to look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540373/using-laplace-transforms-to-solve-a-pde?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made some rushed mistakes and edited the solution. Let me know if you want me to elaborate more.

Comment: I looked at the post you linked and the answer, but I don't quite follow.

Comment: The ODE now looks correct to me. To find the particular solution you can use [this method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second-order_equation).